# SQL TRIGGERS compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

What am I doing wrong here?
I keep getting warning messages with my triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER DateFinDebut AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF dateFin ON SessionUQAM
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    dateFin = DATEADD(day,90,dateDebut);
END;
/

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

Comment: Use `show errors`. But there is no `dateadd()` in Oracle. And you can't assign a value to a column like that. Please go through the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020

Comment: thanks it does help!

Comment: Also, typically, a trigger that updates a column in the same table would be a `BEFORE` trigger rather than an `AFTER` trigger. And you might be better served by making `dateFin` a virtual column and not bothering about a trigger at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing

```
dateFin = DATEADD(day,90,dateDebut);
```

is intended to add 90 days to the current row's `datedebut` value.

In Oracle there is no `dateadd` function. You just add a number of days to a date. In a trigger you need to refer to the current row using the `:new` pseudo-record.

```
:new.datefin := :new.datedebut +90;
```

You can list compilation errors in SQL*Plus using [show errors](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve041.htm#sthref2300), although tools such as [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) (free) and [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) (commercial) will list them more interactively.

Comment: thanks for answering! however I tried your code and I get  "ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers", If I try it without the < :new > then it is created but with compilation errors again... I also tried switching to BEFORE instead of AFTER but with no luck either :(

Comment: `for each row` makes it a row-level trigger that can refer to `:new` and `:old`. Otherwise it's a table-level trigger, which can't.